# Internal port forwarding

Tags: mikrotik-routeros, mikrotik

I use software which connecting to PosgreSQL db. But this SW not able to change port (using default 5432) but my DB is running on 5433. I want to create some internal portforward (e.g. from fake IP address) to real IP of my DB on port 5433. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The port-mapping tool in Windows is the
[Netsh interface portproxy command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy)
and especially the sub-command
[add v4tov4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#add-v4tov4).

The command that may help is similar to:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5432 connectport=5433 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
```

Try to experiment with it and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes. This is working. But I am looking for OS independed solution.

Comment: Another solution is to change the port number of either server or client. Or for a router solution, add to it port-forwarding from port 5432 to 5433. More information about your setup will help.

Comment: It use same subnet. I think that port-forwarding will not work.

Comment: Port-forwarding is only if the connection is via a router.

Comment: Is it possible use Harpin NAT for this?

Comment: @JaSHin: Hairpinning depends on the router.